# Prediction of VAR model with exogenous variables in R

Tags: r, time-series, prediction, var, forecast

I'm building a very simple VAR model of inflation and a fuel price index. My data are from 1998 to Sep 2021. When running the simple VAR model I get a prediction for inflation with no problems whatsoever, however I can't get a prediction when I incorporate a "crisis dummy" as an exogenous variable. This variable has 0's for the most part and 1's when I want to impose a crisis assumption to the data.

```
library(urca)
library(vars)
library(mFilter)
library(tseries)
library(TSstudio)
library(forecast)
library(tidyverse)

#-----Loading the Dataset (283 rows x 4 columns[date, inflation, fuel price index & crisis dummy])
data <- read_csv2(file.choose())
head(data)
nrow(data)

#-----Turning the dataset's variabels into time series in order to apply the model
inf <- ts(data$inflation, start = c(1998,3,1), frequency = 12)
fuel_index <- ts(data$`fuel_ndex_lag2`, start = c(1998,3,1), frequency = 12)
crisis <- ts(data$`crisis`, start = c(1998,3,1), frequency = 12)

#Buidling the Model
v <- cbind(inf, fuel_index) 
lagselect <- VARselect(v, lag.max = 12, type ="both" )
lagselect$selection
lagselect$criteria

#Building the VAR using the (283x1) timeseries object "crisis" as my exogenous variable
var <- VAR(v, p=5, type = "const", season = NULL, exog = crisis)
summary(var)

#-----Loading a CSV file that I've already prepared and turning it into a time series object in #order to use it 
#as the new exogenous variable in the prediction block of the model. Since I will predict for only 1 period ahead,
#this new object is exactly the same as "crisis" but with an additional row (284x1). I fill that row with a 1
#(I also tried leaving the extra row blank)
new_crisis <- read_csv2(file.choose())
new_crisis <- ts(new_crisis$crisis, start = c(1998,3,1), frequency = 12)

#VAR forecasting
var_forecast <- predict(var, dumvar = new_crisis, n.ahead = 1, ci = 0.95)
```

When I run the last command I get the following error message:

> "Error in predict.varest(var, dumvar = new_crisis, n.ahead = 1, ci = 0.95) : Row number of dumvar is unequal to n.ahead."

Since I am predicting for 1 additional period, shouldn't my dumvar value be just one extra row longer than my initial exogenous variable? What am I missing? Also, should this extra row be blank or should I make a decision of whether to fill it with a 1 or 0?

I'll appreciate any help on this.

Comment: `new_crisis` must have just one value, as you are only predicting for one period. It should not be blank, it must be numeric (0 or 1 if it is a dummy).

Comment: I still get the same error